# gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion errors filling up the syslog

Tags: gnome, syslog

I'm on a bare-bones, minimum install of Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS, 64-bit, on a pretty limited machine.  With this minimum install, the syslog is filling up with error messages:

```
gnome-shell[4500]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
gnome-shell[4500]: message repeated 277 times [ gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed]
gsd-media-keys[4627]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
gsd-media-keys[4627]: message repeated 277 times [ gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed]
```

over and over and over and over again.  I have tried switching to Xorg as another users reported that this resulted in one (1) throw of the error, but I did that and there was no change.  I had to limit the size of the syslog to prevent this from completely filling up my drive.

I'm very new to unix, so I'm not really sure how to find out what it is that is causing this error to endlessly repeat.  I've Googled for information but don't find much that is later than 2022 (except for the one Xorg-related solution, which as mentioned did not work for me).

What commands, if any, can I use to track down the source of this error message?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I had the same problem. It was getting so bad that it was difficult to watch a net' video since the audio kept halting while it logged the GVC error to /var/log/syslog.

Browsing the web, I came across **pavucontrol**

```
sudo apt install pauvcontrol
```

Running it and selecting the right-most tab **Configuration**, the 'Built-n Audio Profile' setting kept randomly cycling through the available profiles:

- Analog Stereo Duplex
- Digital Stereo Duplex (IEC958)
- Analog Surround 7.1 Output

...etc.

Closing all audio apps and browser, then restarting pauvcontrol, the Profile finally settled down, and I was able to select 'Analog Stereo Output'.

Doing that seems to have solved it: no errors logged; audio plays without hesitation.

Just to check, I re-selected the 'Analog Stereo Duplex' profile.  Sure enough, the errors returned...